# Camera MIPI CSI2 vs Camera serial parallel interface

Tags: video, interface, camera

I have got a question on the CPI (Camera Parallel interface) and MIPI CSI2 (Camera Serial interface).
as some video interface in the camera are using the CPI, but in the ECU side, from Deserializer to SoC they will use MIPI CSI2.
Whether the serializer using CPI is compatiable with deserializer using MIPI CSI2?
Only video stream bandwidth to be considered here is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

after checking some documentation on TI and MAXIM, there is no relationship between MIPI and Parallel transportation. the serializer and deserializer can handled it directly. What we shall do is check the datasheet for the SERDES